# how to deploying nextjs app integrated with react and redux on cpanel

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

In react you can transfer static files in the build folder to cpanel, direct admin or other shared server. 
What is the solution for nextjs? 
without using the nodejs and install it on the server

Comment: How would you be using NextJS without installing Node first?

Comment: `$ next build` then take your build folder and put it on the server via FTP

Comment: in .next folder index.html file not exist

Comment: @MehrdadMasoumi Did you find any solutions for above problem,I am also facing the same issue. I am not sure how to deploy it to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not generate dynamic pages at runtime you can use nextjs export static which will generate static HTML for you and then you could deploy on cpanel

Comment: pages are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I found the way myself.

On a dedicated server, as long as you are connected to the server using Putty, you can load the site by creating a virtual host. by example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName digiattar.com
   ServerAlias www.digiattar.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full

   <Proxy *>
       Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you enter the domain address in the browser, the server points to the localhost address and port 8080, on which Nextjs is running.

After completing the steps, you can go to the root of your project and run Nextjs as like it is on your computer using the command npm run dev or next start or etc

but after close putty everything expire, using pm2 for this problem